# How do you find a player with a score in 1.13.1?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Say there was a scoreboard objective called money, and say they had 1 money. How do I see if a player has at least 1 money? as in `/testfor @a[score_money_min=1]`, except using /execute or something in 1.13.1? I am currently trying to make a Vanilla Server for fun. I am currently making a custom command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: I understand what you want now. Thank you for clarifying in your question. It is rather tricky since /testfor is removed in 1.13. The command for checking the minimum count for objective "money" in 1.13.1 would be:

```
/execute if entity @a[scores={money=1..}]
```

The two dots after the 1 are correct, they mean "greater than". See the following wiki page for more information of selecting targets by score:

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selector_arguments

Hope that helps.

Comment: sorry, wrong kind of seeing i guess. thanks for trying to help though! I appreciate it.

Comment: I updated the answer. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you so much. you are highly appreciated.i hope i can answer some of your questions.

Comment: The two dots means "greater than or equal to," from my experience.